# How to expose C++ classes from many files from Rcpp modules

Tags: r, rcpp

Is it possible to expose C++ classes defined across many source and header files to R through an Rcpp module? My project has potentially many dozens of C++ source and header files. Is it possible to `#include` these headers into one single `cpp` file that handles the `RCPP_MODULE` statements? I have only seen simple examples where the `RCPP_MODULE` statements are in the `cpp` files of each pair of `cpp` and `hpp` files. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I am just learning Rcpp for a project. I am comparing it to a Python/Cython workflow. So far, I'm very impressed.

Comment: "I guess" but you have nothing concrete here so this is unanswerable.

Comment: Say I have Foo.cpp and Foo.hpp, as well as Bar.cpp and Bar.hpp. The only examples that I have seen have had the RCPP_MODULE statements in both Foo.cpp and Bar.cpp separately. Could I instead have them both in a single separate file called something like Module.cpp, in which I would #include both Foo.hpp and Bar.hpp and expose the classes defined therein to R? I'm not sure if this is how it works.Do the RCPP_MODULE statements have to be in the same cpp files as the classes they are exposing?

Comment: Yes, see eg [here from RcppAnnoy](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppannoy/blob/master/src/annoy.cpp).